# RabbitMQ Producer Threadpool

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq, threadpoolexecutor

According to the documentation, RabbitMQ has a threadpool for each RabbitMQ `Connection`(as opposed to channel).

http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/Limitations-with-RabbitMQ-Java-Client-tp30727p30768.html

This makes a sensible default. You can have a queue per connection, and each queue would have a max of 5 worker threads picking up requests. However, nothing is said about the number of threads for the Producer. The blanket statement that each connection has a threadpool of max 5 threads implicitly means that each Producer that establishes a new channel on the connection to the RabbitMQ broker which will also be bound to the same type of threadpool.

If that's the case, would each call to `sendMessage` end up using the threadpool?

Answer (score 0):

You should have one Channel per thread instead of a Connection. You should have only one connection.

There is no limit of "publisher-threads" however you can send one message at a time per channel.

By considering you are using a similar code

```
channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
```

Comment: Sorry I meant channel not Connection.

Comment: I did, if you bothered to check. I understand that there is one channel per thread and one connection per queue, I established that in the question. The question is, does `sendMessage` use different threads in the threadpool to send messages to rabbitmq